# Python/django error: 'myapp' is not a registered namespace

Tags: python, django, namespaces

I am facing a very unusual problem.

I've registered the namespace `myapp` using `app_name` in my main project's `urls.py` file like this:

```
app_name = 'myapp'
```

I'm writing a view where the user registers and is redirected to the homepage. However, when I'm using the redirect function in myapp's `views.py` file like this:

```
return redirect('myapp: index')
```

I'm getting the following error after clicking the registration form's submit button:

```
NoReverseMatch at /
'myapp' is not a registered namespace
```

I tired looking for a solution but to no avail. Help please :)

Comment: How are you including your app's URLs in your site `urls.py` file?

Comment: Currently, I'm just having a single app. Hence I haven't created an app-specific `urls.py` file. I only have the main project's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
app_name = 'myapp'
```

is meant to be put [in an *included* `urls.py`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces-and-included-urlconfs). It has no effect in a `urls.py` that is not included in another.

I recommend moving your URLs into the app and including them in your site's `urls.py`. Then your namespace should work.