# 'products' is not a registered namespace

Tags: django

I'm running into a problem. I'm getting the following error message in django:

I've got this link:

```
<a class="prods" href="{% url 'accounts:products' %}">
```

I'm getting this error:

```
'products' is not a registered namespace
```

I've defined 'products' in the primary urls.py document:

```
url(r'^products/', include('products.productsurls', namespace='products')),
```

I've also specified the app name within producturls.py.

```
app_name = 'products'
```

Can you think of any other way in which I can define the namespace? This really baffles me.

Thanks!

Comment: hav a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42749507/python-django-error-myapp-is-not-a-registered-namespace)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `app_name = 'websites'` you can use for url resolving following name `'websites:urlname'` also. You can find more details [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#id4).

**UPD**

Looks like the problem is here:

```
<a class="prods" href="{% url 'accounts:products' %}">
```

In this case `account` is namespase. And `product` is pattern name. So to use `'accounts:products'` url name you need to have patterns like this:

```
# main urls.py
url(r'^products/', include('products.productsurls', namespace='accounts')),

# productsurls.py
path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='products'),
```

But with you following urls it should be something like this:

```
<a class="prods" href="{% url 'products:urlname' %}">
```

Comment: Sorry, I copied the wrong line.  The app name is actually set to products  app_name = 'products'